# Custom domain for b2clogin.com/Frontdoor proxy and DNS issues

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Per following article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow) to verify custom domain for Azure B2C you need to create TXT record. 
As an example if I want to handle login at `login.mycompany.com`, I need to create TXT record `login.mycompany.com` with value of `MS=ms12345678`. But this domain also have to be hosted on Azure FrontDoor and hence you also need to create CNAME record for `login.mycompany.com` pointing to `<....>.azurefd.net`. 
Issue is that you can not have both records at the same time (TXT record and CNAME record for the same name). How is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that as a first step you have to verify your custom domain name with Azure AD B2C. Once it is done, you have to delete the DNS TXT record you created, this is mentioned in the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow#step-1-add-a-custom-domain-name-to-your-azure-ad-b2c-tenant

[image]

Then you setup your custom domain on the Azure Front Door:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-domain?pivots=b2c-user-flow#step-3-set-up-your-custom-domain-on-azure-front-door

This is my final setup for the AD B2C custom domain on the Azure AD B2C side:

[image]

Here is the Azure Front Door frontend with my custom domain:

[image]

Here is DNS configuration in DNS Registrar:

[image]